# Do not want to create folder instrumentscli.trace in project of IntelliJ IDEA when run UIAutomation in Xcode

Tags: automation, xcode-instruments

I am new to UIAutomation instrument in Xcode 7. Everytime I run UIAutomation with command line:

```
String results = commandPrompt.runCommand("instruments -w "+ IOSConfig.udid
    + " -t /Users/hunter/Documents/UiAutomation_Xcode_Template/MyTemplate "
    + app.getAbsolutePath() + " -e UIARESULTSPATH /Users/hunter/Documents/Documents/UiAutomation_Xcode_Template");
```

my project creates a new folder "instrumentscli*X*.trace".

[image: instrumentscli0_image]

I do not want those folders to be created.

Please help me!
Many thanks!